# Error while comparing dates in different formats

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am getting the following error when the below codesnippet is getting executed,i gave the sample inputs for "DueDate" and "
"CreatedDate",is it because both of them are in different time formats?how to convert the "DueDate" into the same format as"
Created Date"

Error:-

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Text' and 'datetime.datetime
```

CODE SNIPPET:-

```
if ((None != DueDate) and ((DueDate - CreatedDate).days < 1)):
```

SAMPLE INPUT:-

```
DueDate
2/6/2015
CreatedDate
2015-02-03 20:15:47.950000
```

Comment: The error message is pretty explanatory. You'll have to convert the string to a datetime object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to convert your date string to a `datetime` object. There is no implicit conversion from a string to a `datetime` object. You could try something like the following.

```
import datetime

date = "3/17/2015"

# I used now in place of your datetime object CreatedDate
datetime_object = datetime.datetime.now()

due_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")

if due_date != None and (datetime_object - due_date).days < 1:
    print("clever message")
```

## Edit

Thanks to the comment by @J.F.Sebatian I took out the first method using `time.strptime`. See the comment below for details.

Comment: unrelated: don't use `fromtimestamp(mktime(time_tuple))` to get a datetime object, use `datetime(*time_tuple[:6])` instead. `mktime()` and `fromtimestamp()` may return a wrong result for some input if the local timezone has different utc offsets on different dates as many timezones do. It would be even better if you leave only `datetime.strptime()` code in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! That's good to know. I made the necessary changes

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the 'date' objects you defined, i.e. DueDate and CreatedDate,  are of two different types (resp. 'Text' and timedate.timedate) and there is no such operation as difference available for them.

From Python documentation, see e.g., https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html:

> class datetime.**timedelta**
>
> A duration expressing the difference between two date, time, or datetime  instances to microsecond resolution.

So you can certainly consider the difference of two datetime.datetime objects once you have redefined DueDate (formerly of type 'Text') as a datetime.datetime object, e.g.:

```
DueDate = datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 2, 0, 0)
```